# How to make dynamic id inside xml tag

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I need to replace the id of the tag entry-field `$BA01` with dynamique one . So the part `$BA0` stay static but 1 will be dynamique.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<panel caption="operators" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../action-panel.xsd">
<group orientation="vertical" >
<group orientation="horizontal" >
<label drivedText="%NumberOfOperator('1')" />
</group>
<group orientation="horizontal" >
<entry-field id="$BA01" />
</group>
....
</group>
</panel>
```

I have tried this method bellow but it did not work to concat those values inside id especially it is fieldsEnumeration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<panel caption="operators" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../action-panel.xsd">
<group orientation="vertical" >
<group orientation="horizontal" >
<label drivedText="%NumberOfOperator('1')" />
</group>
<group orientation="horizontal" >
<entry-field id="$BA0%NumberOfOperator('1')" />
</group>
....
</group>
</panel>

%NumberOfOperator('1') return 1.
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand you question. What did you mean for "dynamic id"?
Anyway, I think you can do this using, for example, Javascript, that I think is the simplest way.
Using the DOM, you can access the child you are interested in.
Let xml be the variable containing the reference to your XML file, then:

> var entryField = xml.getElementsByTagName('entry-field') //entryField
>   is an array containing all the childs
>  //having tag name
>   "entry-field"
>  //suppose for simplicity that entryField has only
>   one element
>  entryField.setAttribute("id","new_id") //so you can
>   change dynamically your attribute

I hope this could be useful. For questions do not hesitate to ask.